# Cannot initialize a std::vector of objects when class contains std::thread

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

I'm running into an error with a more complicated class structure which I have boiled down to the below simple test case.  The actual intent is to use a ctor with parameters, but the error occurs even when explicitly calling the empty ctor.

```
class TestFun{
public:
    explicit TestFun(const std::function<void()>& fun) : m_thread(fun) {}
    ~TestFun() {m_thread.join();}
private:
    std::thread m_thread;
};

class Test : public TestFun{
public:
    Test() : TestFun( [this](){std::cout << "test\n";}) {}
};

std::vector<Test> tests(10);           // This compiles
std::vector<Test> tests(10, Test());   // This gives an error
```

The error is:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:288:63: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from input type
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Your class is not copyable so you can't make 10 copies of `Test()`

Comment: What would it mean to have multiple copies of the same `thread` object? Multiple different threads? Multiple owners of the same thread?

Comment: Why does the first form (without explicitly calling the ctor) work?

Comment: The first one default-constructs the suckers in place. The second one tries to copy-construct from the given instance.

Comment: The lightbulb has been lit.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) on `std::vector` constructor on this line:

```
std::vector<Test> tests(10);           // This compiles
```

you use

> 4. Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.

on another side on this line:

```
std::vector<Test> tests(10, Test());   // This gives an error
```

you try to use another variant:

> 3. Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value.

As `std::thread` is not copy constructible it implicitly deletes default copy constructor of you class, so this variant does not compile.

From [`std::thread` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

> No two std::thread objects may represent the same thread of execution;
> std::thread is not CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable, although it is
> MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable.

Comment: Side note: this is where defaulting a special member function can help you out. The error message raised at `Test(const Test &) = default;` may be be easier to understand. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/YzjnYPnd3 Visual studio comes out and tells you in nearly plain English with or without the default . With clang it tells you the problem with the default but without the default you have to wade through a few dozen lines of template expansion crawl. GCC isn't nearly so polite in either case.